# GPTK Steam Can't open UI; steamwebhelper is not responding

Tags: games, steam, sonoma

After updating my MacBook Pro to Mac OS Sonoma, I've tried to install Apple's **G**ame **P**orting **T**ool**k**it (GPTK).

I've followed the [AppleGamingWiki guide](https://www.applegamingwiki.com/wiki/Game_Porting_Toolkit).

---

Unfortunately, after installing + starting Steam using these 2 commands, I get the error as shown below:

```bash
# Install
gameportingtoolkit ~/my-game-prefix ~/Downloads/SteamSetup.exe

# Run
gameportingtoolkit ~/my-game-prefix 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe'
```

Error:
[image]

---

I came across [a github issue](https://github.com/Whisky-App/Whisky/issues/41) that [suggested](https://github.com/Whisky-App/Whisky/issues/41#issuecomment-1596364647) to manually start `steamwebhelper.exe` and `steamservice.exe` before starting `steam.exe`. I've tried that, but the same error occurs.

Somebody else [suggested](https://github.com/Whisky-App/Whisky/issues/41#issuecomment-1585640483) to copy the `config`, `registry.vdf` and `userdata` files from the MacOs Steam to the Windows variant, again, the same error occurs.

Another [suggestion](https://github.com/Whisky-App/Whisky/issues/41#issuecomment-1601086964) that didn't work was to launch Steam using these arguments:
`-allosarches -cef-force-32bit`.

---

Does somebody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: If somebody with 150+ rep could tag this on [tag:gptk], that would be nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with [gptk](/questions/tagged/gptk) for a while, I've found a set of commands that seem to work.

---

1. Kill all running `wine64-preloader` commands:

   ```
   killall wine64-preloader
   ```
2. Place the '[Replacement command](https://www.applegamingwiki.com/wiki/Game_Porting_Toolkit#Replacement)' in your `~/.zshrc`:

   <sup>**Note**: Don't forget to replace `~/my-game-prefix` with your chosen prefix</sup>

   ```
   wine-gptk(){ WINEESYNC=1 WINEPREFIX=~/my-game-prefix $(brew --prefix game-porting-toolkit)/bin/wine64 "$@"; }
   ```

   I'm not sure why, but this command seem to work a lot better then directly running
   `game-porting-toolkit`
3. Restart your terminal to enable the `wine-gptk` command

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```
4. Enable `x86_64` shell:

   ```
   arch -x86_64 zsh
   ```
5. Start Steam

   ```
   wine-gptk 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe'
   ```
6. (Optionally) Since some game's wont launch from Steam, start the `.exe` manually in a new terminal window after starting Steam, eg:

   ```
   wine-gptk 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Zeepkist\Zeepkist.exe'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for u, worked with me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_QfDyFaM7s

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).